# Add vertical scrollbar to an ExtJS panel which contains 4 other components

Tags: extjs, scrollbar, treegrid

I have create a Ext.Panel with layout 'hbox', added 4 children, tree grids with the same store and want now to have a single vertical scrollbar for all of them and scroll only the content of the grids and not the headers. I searched through the containing Panel options and scrollable option will scroll the entire layout so, the optional horizontal scrollbars of the children will disappear. Can someone to give me a hint from where to start, what option/component to use to accomplish this single vertical scrollbar?

Why I put 4 tree grids in the same panel using the same store? Because the last one is a Bryntum Gantt component. The first column of the first grid should scroll horizontal when the items are too long and don't want to use ellipsis CSS property on the cells. And from time to time I need to switch the Gantt to another grid with more details. Also the second tree has only dates columns on them and have to be locked whenever gantt or other child toggles visibility.

I use ExtJS 6.0.1 Classic.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you want to keep the headers, you cannot use the panel scroller. Instead, you have to create mutual partnerships between the grid scrollers:

```
Ext.each(grids,function(grid) {
    if(grid.normalGrid) grid = grid.normalGrid; // Use the normal subgrid of a grid with locked columns.
    Ext.each(grids,function(partner) {
        if(partner.normalGrid) partner = partner.normalGrid; // Use the normal subgrid of a grid with locked columns.
        if(grid != partner) grid.getView().getScrollable().addPartner(partner.getView().getScrollable(), "y"); // "y" tells the scrollable that the partnership is only regarding y axis.
    });
});
```

This forces them to stay in sync, [as per the docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.1/classic/Ext.scroll.Scroller.html#method-addPartner).

Comment: There is an issue, thought. Let's assume I scroll the grid to some middle point. If I switch the details pane with the Gantt and vice-versa, the new revealed grid will have the scrollY set to 0. Is there some way to refresh the scroll even if the grid is hidden for the moment?

Comment: From the top of my head, something like this should suffice: `somegrid.on('show',function() {somegrid.getScroller().scrollTo({y:someOtherGrid.getScroller().getPosition().y})`. If you use a card layout instead of show/hide, it's not `show` event, but `activate`.

Comment: Perfect and perfect. I had some errors on `getScroller()` function, I think it is deprecated or something, in my Ext version, so, instead, I used `somegrid.getView().getScrollY()`, but, eventually works like a charm. You saved my day. **10x**